# LESS en lugar de CSS

Tags: css, gulp, navegador-web, less

Tengo una duda sobre la parte servidor donde el renderizado de los estilos, al menos con Chrome y FireFox.

Y es que estos usan el .LESS en lugar del .CSS. En desarrollo está bien que me los muestre, ya que así es mucho más fácil saber que retocar si hiciera falta.

Lo que no entiendo es por qué en el entorno del servidor que no es de desarrollo donde únicamente subo los .CSS está cogiendo estos archivos .LESS (y que además, no están actualizados a la última versión).

Uso GULP, gulp-less, gulp-autoprefixer, gulp-sourcemaps y browser-sync. Estos ficheros tampoco se suben al entorno del servidor.

No se si a alguien más le ha pasado esto, pero es algo que no me gusta mucho que ocurre, y menos si no está actualizado cuando todo lo está en desarrollo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los navegadores no usan ficheros LESS, usan los CSS. Pero existen los llamados *source maps*. Seguramente tu fichero CSS incluye un comentario tipo:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=/path/to/file.css.map
```

Que le indica a tu navegador dónde obtener ese fichero.
O, directamente, lo introduce como binario embebido:

```
/*# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,ewoJInZlcnNpb24iOiAzJImZpbGUi...
```

Lo cual deberías evitar en producción porque significa que ha metido todas las fuentes dentro del fichero resultado, y a menudo ocupa más esta parte que el resultado en sí.

De un modo u otro, con esta información el navegador es capaz de reconstruir el fichero original y permitirte debugar viendo tus fuentes. Esto funciona tanto para CSS como para Javascript: aquí tienes un ejemplo con Typescript que el builder de Angular mapea y ofrece al navegador:

[image: Typescript en Chrome]

Comment: ¡Grácias! En gulp usamos los sourcemaps para que en desarrollo podamos ver las líneas mejor para cambiar los atributos. Pues cuando hagamos subidas a producción eliminamos esa línea.